# Wrong ip in serialized dask.distributed.Queue() objects: Failed to deserialize

Tags: docker-compose, distributed, dask

I am running a small dask distributed cluster using docker-compose (also tested using docker swarm), and connecting to it from my local laptop.

I'm trying to run a small test using dask.distributed.Queue(). Those do not deserialize properly on the workers, as they contain the ip:port used to connect to the cluster (scheduler) from my local laptop, not the ip available inside the docker compose virtual network.

How should I connect to the cluster, or set the cluster up, so that Queue() objects serialize with the proper scheduler address?

Error messages:

```
distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to deserialize b'\x80\x04\x95\x9b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x12distributed.queues\x94\x8c\x05Queue\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94\x8c&queue-7f344bb49fac489e9b330c7ec5ebb736\x94\x8c\x14tcp://localhost:8786\x94\x86\x94bh\x02)\x81\x94\x8c&queue-896fde1ea60a426f98846735372b33c7\x94h\x05\x86\x94b\x86\x94.'

OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://localhost:8786' after 10 s: in <distributed.comm.tcp.TCPConnector object at 0x7ffa5cc49588>: OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Test code:

```
import dask.distributed
import dask.bag as db

client = dask.distributed.Client('localhost:8786')

q = dask.distributed.Queue()

def foo(q1, q2):
  while True:
    d = q1.get()
    print(d)
    q2.put(d)


q1 = dask.distributed.Queue()
q2 = dask.distributed.Queue()
client.submit(foo, q1, q2)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  scheduler:
    hostname: scheduler
    image: daskdev/dask
    command: dask-scheduler
    ports:
      - "8786:8786"
      - "8787:8787"
    volumes:
      - /:/host
  worker-1:
    hostname: worker-1
    image: daskdev/dask
    command: dask-worker scheduler:8786
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    volumes:
      - /:/host
```